# Scan 2 Strings and give points for each right char

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, char

```
String[] ergebnisse = {"Err", "Baum", "Schule", "Pferd", "Maschine"};
String eingabe = textField1.getText();
int[] punkte = new int[ergebnisse.length];

for (int w = 0; w < ergebnisse.length; w++) {
      for (int b = 0; b < ergebnisse[w].length(); b++) {
        if (ergebnisse[w].charAt(b) == eingabe.charAt(b)) {
          punkte[w]++;   
        }
      }
    }
```

Error Oud of Bounds only apears in the if case on the second run.
if i replace if(ergebnisse[w].charAt(b)) == eingabe.charAt(X))
it works but only for thr one caracter.

Comment: Please show a complete, minimal, runnable example *that doesn't use Swing*. But think about why `eingabe.charAt(b)` might cause this problem? Have you stepped through your code with the debugger?

Comment: What are the constraints on `eingabe`? Is there something that forces its length to be equal to or longer than the length of the longest element of  `ergebnisse` ? If there isn't, you should guard against that possibility.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's say you input "Pferd".

Your code runs once for each `ergebnisse`, so eventually it gets to `Schule`.

schule's length is 6, of course. So that `for (int b` ) loop is going to run 6 times. Unfortunately, you're going to run into real issues on that 6th run (where `b` is `5`): `eingabe.charAt(5)` - **that does not work** - there is no 6th character in `eingabe`, as eingabe has only 5 letters in it.

The fix is to deal with that. You can't switch it up and change the loop to `for (int b = 0; b < eingabe.length(); b++)` either - what if the eingabe is longer than one of the ergebnisse?

You could go by whichever one is smaller:

```
for (int b = 0; i < Math.min(eingabe.length(), ergebnisse[w].length()); b++)`
```

You could also simply 'detect' this is pick some action:

```
if (b < eingabe.length() && ergebnisse[w].charAt(b) == eingabe.charAt(b)) {
```

for example.

You need to pick one of the two to 'scan length'

Comment: `for (int b = 0; b < ergebnisse[w].length() && b < eingabe.length(); b++) {` is another way of limiting the values that index `b` ranges over.